# django restframework in login module authenticate() not working

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-rest-framework

```
email = request.data.get('email', None)
password = request.data.get('password', None)
account = authenticate(email=email, password=password)
```

I am using an authenticate() function but it always returns None.
Can you suggest some modifications to rectify the function.

Comment: have you overridden `authenticate`? Django's `authenticate` doesn't authenticate against an email address

Comment: how can we overridden authenticate...?

Answer (score 0):

By default django uses name to fetch/authenticate users from request. So you have to set `USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'` in your User model.

[Check the DJango docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.CustomUser)

> A string describing the name of the field on the user model that is used as the unique identifier. This will usually be a username of some kind, but it can also be an email address, or any other unique identifier. The field must be unique (i.e., have unique=True set in its definition), unless you use a custom authentication backend that can support non-unique usernames.

Also since you are using DRF make sure the CBVs you use does not override `authentication_classes`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the syntax for authenticate

```
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
```

Here username is USERNAME_FIELD value of the user model. By default its value is 'username' so the authenticate method will automatically check for username and password combination. to change the user to be authenticated with email we have to set `USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'`.

```
user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
```